# plt.scatter plot turns out blank

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

the code below returns a blank plot in Python:

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

os.chdir('file path')

# import data files
activity = pd.read_csv('file path\dailyActivity_merged.csv')
intensity = pd.read_csv('file path\hourlyIntensities_merged.csv')
steps = pd.read_csv('file path\hourlySteps_merged.csv')
sleep = pd.read_csv('file path\sleepDay_merged.csv')

# ActivityDate in activity df only includes dates (no time). Rename it Dates
activity = activity.rename(columns={'ActivityDate': 'Dates'})

# ActivityHour in intensity df and steps df includes date-time. Split date-time column into dates and times in intensity. Drop the date-time column

intensity['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(intensity['ActivityHour']).dt.date
intensity['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(intensity['ActivityHour']).dt.time
intensity = intensity.drop(columns=['ActivityHour'])

# split date-time column into dates and times in steps. Drop the date-time column

steps['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(steps['ActivityHour']).dt.date
steps['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(steps['ActivityHour']).dt.time
steps = steps.drop(columns=['ActivityHour'])

# split date-time column into dates and times in sleep. Drop the date-time column

sleep['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(sleep['SleepDate']).dt.date
sleep['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(sleep['SleepDate']).dt.time
sleep = sleep.drop(columns=['SleepDate', 'TotalSleepRecords'])

# add a column & calculate time_awake_in_bed before falling asleep

sleep['time_awake_in_bed'] = sleep['TotalTimeInBed'] - sleep['TotalMinutesAsleep']

# merge activity and sleep
list = ['Id', 'Dates']
activity_sleep = sleep.merge(activity,
                on = list,
                how = 'outer')

# plot relation between calories used daily vs how long it takes users to fall asleep

plt.scatter(activity_sleep['time_awake_in_bed'], activity_sleep['Calories'], s=20, c='b', marker='o')
plt.axis([0, 200, 0, 5000])
plt.show()
```

NOTE: max(Calories) = 4900 and min(Calories) =0. max(time_awake_in_bed) = 0 and min(time_awake_in_bed) = 150

Please let me know how I can get a scatter plot out of this. Thank you in advance for any help.

The same variables from the same data-frame work perfectly with geom_point() in R.

Comment: I was able to create the graphs fine with dummy data. Check if the numbers you have are very small or very large. You can comment the `plt.axis()` line, see if the data is created ok as well. time_awake_in_bed should be between 0-200 and Calories between 0-5000

Comment: With `plt.axis()` you are changing the axis limits, i.e., in which range data is shown. Most likely, the values are not correct and thus no data is shown. But without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we cannot know for sure.

Comment: @Redox Commented out plt.axis() but still get a blank figure. The range makes sense though as max(Calories) = 4900 and min(Calories) =0. max(time_awake_in_bed) = 0 and min(time_awake_in_bed) = 150

Comment: @СергейКох I've now provided my fill code.

Comment: @cheersmate I think the range makes sense. Please see my reply to Redox

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was. As @Redox and @cheersmate mentioned in comments, the data-frame that I created by merging included NaN values. I fixed this by merging them only on 'Id'. Then I could create a scatter plot:

```
list = ['Id']
activity_sleep = sleep.merge(activity,
                on = list,
                how = 'outer')
```

The column "Dates" is not a good one to merge on, as in each data frame the same dates are repeated in multiple rows. Also I noticed that I get the same plot whether I outer or inner merge. Thank you.